What's the syntax to create a non standard HTML attribute in Reagent/Hiccup?
What's the syntax to create this HTML in Reagent/Hiccup?
<span custom-attribute="value"></span>

Reagent and Hiccup docs fail to mention it.
Standard attributes are added by using a {:keyword "value"} map, but only if :keyword is valid. I didn't find docs to add any arbitrary attribute.

[:span {"custom-attribute" "value"}]

From Reagent's docs: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/UsingHiccupToDescribeHTML.md#creating-non-standard-html-attributes
